# What is wrong with the form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a online Phone Book for my locality. I am getting problem with the app's entry creation view.

Here is my PhoneEntry model:

```
# coding=utf-8
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class PhoneEntry(models.Model):
    # Name of the organisation
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Organisation's Name")
    org_details = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, verbose_name="Organisation's Details")
    slug = models.SlugField(default='slug', unique=True)

    # Verified or not
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

    # Dates when the entry was added and verified
    added_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    verified_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edited_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)

    # The phone numbers of the organisation
    primary_ph_number = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name="Primary Phone Number")
    secondary_ph_number = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name="Secondary Phone Number", blank=True)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        super(PhoneEntry, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
        self.slug = slugify(self.org_name+"-"+str(int(self.id)))
        super(PhoneEntry, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

    @staticmethod
    def get_absolute_url():
        return reverse_lazy('phbook:index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.org_name+"-"+str(self.primary_ph_number)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Phone Entries"
```

And this the EntryCreateForm:

```
class EntryAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """org_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="Enter your organisation name: ")
    org_details = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.Textarea,
                                  label="Enter your organisation details: ", required=False)"""
    primary_ph_number = PhoneNumberField(label="Enter your primary phone number: ")
    secondary_ph_number = PhoneNumberField(label="Enter your secondary phone number: ", required=False)

class Meta:
    model = PhoneEntry
    exclude = ['slug', 'last_edited_date', 'added_date', 'verified_date', 'verified']
```

And this the EntryAddView:

```
class EntryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = PhoneEntry
    form_class = EntryAddForm
    template_name = 'phbook/form.html'
    success_url = 'phbook:index'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        print("Data is", form.instance)

        model = form.save(commit=False)
        print(model.org_name, model.org_details, model.primary_ph_number, model.secondary_ph_number)
        model.save()
        return self.get_success_url()
```

And the template form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
    <title>Add your Organisation's Entry | PhoneBook</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'phbook:add' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The base.html contains only the static links for the foundation css and js files.
In the EntryCreateView, when the line `print("Data is ", form.instance)` is executed it produced this result
[image]

Please tell me what I am doing here??

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Copy and paste the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You've overridden `post` on the view, and are therefore bypassing all the calls to validation that the CreateView would normally do. There is rarely any good reason to override the `get` or `post` methods; you should always define a more specific method; in this case, `form_valid` would be more appropriate, if all you want to do is print out the submitted data. If that's just for debugging, then you may not need to override any methods at all.

Comment: I tried it much before but still then the error would occur. If you see the traceback screenshot, then you would see that form didn't have anything in it!!